git clone fails on NFSv4 share when ACL is set
Our Linux servers mount NFSv4 shares exported from an Azure NFS server.
The findmount commands gives this detail.
rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.11.12.43,local_lock=none,addr=10.11.12.40

If I try cloning a remote repo into a directory on the nfs share, I see errors like this:
13:28:18.732963 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects: 100% (599/599), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (599/599), done.
13:28:18.732988 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< PACK ...
13:28:18.897448 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Total 6253 (delta 354), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 5652
remote: Total 6253 (delta 354), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 5652
13:28:18.897472 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< 0000
Receiving objects: 100% (6253/6253), 3.27 MiB | 19.71 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4253/4253), done.
fatal: fsync error on '/foo/bar/default/moo/demand_planning/demand_planning_2029/.git/objects/pack/tmp_idx_Da071c': Permission denied
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

We also saw this error.
fatal: error when closing loose object file: Permission denied

The ACL on /foo/bar/default/moo/demand_planning/demand_planning_2029 looks like this but any ACL using a SCIM group GID will cause git to choke.
A:fdg:383616511:rwaDxtTnNcCy
A:fdg:OWNER@:rwaDxtTnNcCy
A:g:GROUP@:rxtncy
A::EVERYONE@:rxtncy

I tried setting "git config core.fsyncObjectFiles false" to the directory (after "git init") but that didn't help.
